# Adding views to a rootController in a splitView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am playing a little with the split view of iPad and I want to add different views to the rootView of the split. I can add one image, one view of one of my view controllers but, instead of that, I have problems with de rotations.

For example, sometimes appear a white bar on the top and I can't do anything to move it. Does someones know how to add views to the rootView perfectly? Is this correct or I have to make other things.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolve the problem: When I dismiss the popover I have to get out the animation. If I do this, all works fine.

But if someone can tell me the best practices to how to put views in root controller please :)